# What is the best way to do collision detection with rays in processing?

Tags: processing

Say I have a set of n line segments or circles and a ray with an origin and a direction, and I want to know which of these n objects the ray will hit first, or if it will hit any of them at all. Naively I can just do n different checks. My first concern is runtime. Can I do better than O(n)? My other concern is numerical errors. If I try to find the intersection of a ray with a circle, there's going to be some square roots and division. How can I best find the point of intersection without too much error? If it helps, my end goal is to have the ray bounce of these objects like mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

Try the naive solution first. My guess is this will be fine for your purposes.

From there, you might investigate more advanced data structures like [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) which allow you to only check a subset of shapes for potential collisions.

But chances are you won't need them anyway. Do the simple thing first.